# Reset root password in MySQL

Tags: mysql, linux, password, root

I am logging in with root user in MySQL, and the server has been hardened, so this parameter is set `default-authentication-plugin=caching_sha2_password`, and this is currently the only user I have.

getting the following error:
`ERROR 1820 (HY000): You must reset your password using ALTER USER statement before executing this statement.`

Comment: *Reset root password in MySQL* https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html Use generic instructions. *getting the following error* https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-user.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY 'password';
```

This worked for me.